# Can't make stoploss move to breakeven because of variables inside in "if"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When entry_condition is met, Long position is opened, and at the same time i need the program to remember under what conditions is it necessary to move stoploss to entry point(so it will breakeven if somethings will go wrong).

I tried to use "if" to check conditions, and save parameters to variables, and then use it outside "if", but it seems like programs just don't see them outside "if".

Here is what I got:

```
if entry_condition
    var BEcondition = low - 1 * (high - low)
    var BE = low
    var BEbar = "Short1" + str.tostring(bar_index)
if close == BEcondition
    strategy.exit("Short BE", BEbar, stop = BE)
```

I tried using variables without "var" and result was the same. Also I tried using `strategy.position_size`, but my strategy sometimes can have multiple Longs and Shorts at the same time, so I can't figure out how to use it. Is there any way to fix this, or is there alternative ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variables in the global scope and then reassign their values in the if block.

```
var float BEcondition = na
var float BE = na
var string BEbar = na

if entry_condition
    BEcondition := low - 1 * (high - low)
    BE := low
    BEbar := "Short1" + str.tostring(bar_index)
if close == BEcondition
    strategy.exit("Short BE", BEbar, stop = BE)
```